# How to make hyperlink on a String and share in Facebook [iOS]

Tags: ios, facebook

I have a `NSString` which one I use for share on *Facebook* & *Twitter*. My requirement is that text will be a link after share on *Facebook*. On *Facebook* when user click on that text, then direct go to that link.

My code is like below:

```
NSInteger Score = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"K_ScoreVal"];

SLComposeViewController *Facebooksheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
[Facebooksheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just completed level 1.1 and score is %d points.",Score]];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentViewController:Facebooksheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**I just completed level 1.1 and score is 455 points.** This is my text, which one I share on *Facebook*. But when user click on this text, then direct go to a link. Meanwhile I want to make this text as a hyperlink.

Please suggest me.

Comment: this will help you on the clickable part http://stackoverflow.com/a/3169834/1042240

Comment: no i don't want like this. I want when game is over that time automatic the facebook share page is coming with this text. and user can share on facebook. But when i click this text on facebook then it'll be go to link. So how can i implement this hyperlink on text before sharing on Facebook

Comment: You can add url to `SLComposeViewController` using `addURL`. Is that you want?

Comment: yeah i can add url, but that url is showing in Facebook. But i want that text "I just completed level 1.1 and score is 455 points." is showing on facebook and when i click on this text, then it'll go to the url

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to use is the OpenGraph API for games. Have a look at the introduction docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/opengraph/

If you go down this road, you can use the

- [Achievements API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/achievements)
- [Scores API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores)

Comment: no Tobi, i want what i share on Facebook that will be a link. If i click on that text then it'll go to the link :)

Comment: Yeah, that's called OpenGraph objects and actions. Like I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Attributed Strings?

```
NSString *shareString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"I just completed level 1.1 and score is 455 points." attributes:@{NSLinkAttributeName: @"http://yourlink.com"}];
```

Comment: if i take NSAttributedString *shareString instead of NSString *shareString, then when i add this NSAttributedString like this [Facebooksheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",shareString]]; its showing text with this link also

Comment: ya thats ok , but my question is not like that. Please read my question.